# How to reduce code duplication with React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to reduce code duplication. I have a div element within which I display the content which can be either title and detail or only title or only detail. So if there is content, I need to have a close icon next to the content.

Below is the code.

```
let content;
const close_button = <SvgClose onClick={this.props.close} width="28" />;
const title_with_close_button = <Fragment><div className="content"> 
{title}{close_button}</div></Fragment>;
const detail_with_close_button = <Fragment><div className="content"> 
{title}{close_button}</div></Fragment>;

if (title && detail) {
    content = <Fragment><div className="content"> {title}
        {close_button}
    </div>
    <div className="small">
        {detail}
    </div></Fragment>;
} else if (title || detail) {
    content = {title_with_close_button} || {detail_with_close_button};
}
if (content) {
    return (
        <div className="message">
            <div>
                <div>{content}</div>
            </div>
        </div>);
}
```

As you see from the code above, if we have title and detail, then I am using the close button similarly as if I have title or detail). This seems like code duplication. How can I keep the code neat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refactor it to something like this :

```
const close_button = <SvgClose onClick={this.props.close}
  width="28" />;
  return (
    <div className="message">
      <div>
        <div>
          {title
            && <div className="content">
              {title}{close_button}</div>
          }
          {detail
           && <div className={title ? "small" : "content"}>
              {detail}{!title && close_button}</div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

This code :

- Won't display content if there's not title and detail.
- Will display only title or detail with appropriate classes if any one of them is present.
- Will display both with appropriate classes if both of them are present, .i.e, title with `class="content"` and detail with `class="small"`

Although there might be other ways to refactor this, but this is how I prefer - keeping minimum variables.

Comment: thanks. how about solving title && detail condition?

Comment: @stackoverflow_user if title and detail both are there then this will print both. As you can see, both the `div`s will be printed. And when there is `detail` and `title` then the `detail` div has the class `small` and when `title` is not there `detail` div has the class `content`. So this snippet already handles both.

Comment: but then also displays close_button twice if title and detail present. not intended. so added this {detail &&
                            <div className={title ? 'small' : 'content'}>{detail}{title ? null: {close_button}}
                                </div>
                        }

Comment: updated the snippet. sorry about that. idk somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the code to something like this:

```
const close_button = <SvgClose />

    let content = <Fragment>
        <div className="content"> {title && isTitlePresent?close_button:null} </div>
        <div className="small"> {detail && isTitlePresent?null:close_button} </div>
    </Fragment>

if (content) {
    return (
        <div className="message">
            <div>
                <div>{content}</div>
            </div>
        </div>)
}
```